# How to resolve Asyncronous issue in Nested value event listeners in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

1st valueevent listener code is executed first which is after the 2nd value event listener

Value event listener1
{ 
Code1
    { 
       Value event Listener2
         {
            Code2
          }
Code3
}

Code is executed first and before the value event Listener2

I want to execute code sequentially

Like these

Code1
Code2
Code3

Comment: you can call the next listener onComplete method of previous listener

Comment: But they are nested .Means some data used  from code1 to make reference for value event listener 2 and data from value event listener 2 is to use in code3

Comment: Also you can check firebase tasks. https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-1.html

Comment: But they are used to fire listeners.i want to execute code 3 after code 2

Answer (score 1):

Write code 2 in onCompleteListner or onSuccessListner of code 1 and similarly write code 3 in the onCompleteListner or  onSuccessListner  of code 2...